# Attribute Missing from Generated WinForm Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, code-generation, code-analysis

The method definitions in any winform's *.Designer.cs file created by Visual Studio are not decorated with [GeneratedCodeAttribute] attributes. As a result, the generated code is analyzed when I run code metrics or code analysis. Does any one know why the attribute is not provided (it *is* generated code after all)? Would it be safe to add it myself (would it disappear when the code is re-generated, or does generation only occur within the method body)? If I were to add it, what would the proper tool and version strings be for Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is tricky, it isn't actually auto-generated code.  The Designer.cs file is generated by a project item template.  The Windows Forms design-time serializer only regenerates the InitializeComponent() method body and appends control declarations to the bottom of the file.

That doesn't really help you solve your problem.  The most effective fix I can think of is to simply edit the template.  On my machine, that's c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\common7\ide\itemtemplatescache\csharp\windows forms\1033\form.zip\form.designer.cs, put the attribute before the method.  What you use doesn't really matter, no tool is going to expect this attribute to be there.

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of modifying the template; I'll use the template name as the tool name.